# Symfony Form from other Controller

Tags: symfony, view, controller

I have a view that shows the attributes of my parent entity. This Entity will have other child entities. I want the create form for those childs to be placed in my show.html.twig of the parent.

How do I place the create form of those childs in my parents view? How do I combine two controllers of two different entities?

Comment: you can google on embedded forms or take al look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can create forms for any entity in any controller. Since you didn't post any code it's hard to guess how your controller looks like, but here an example that might help:

```
public function showMainEntityAction(MainEntity $mainEntity){

    ...

    $childEntity = new ChildEntity();
    $childEntity->setMainEntity($mainEntity);

    $childEntityForm = $this->createForm(new ChildEntityType(), $childEntity);

    ...

    return $this->render('...show.twig.html', array(
        'entity' => $mainEntity,
        'childEntityForm' => $childEntityForm
    );
}
```

Of course you have to define a form type for the child entities and add `form_widget(childEntityForm)` to your template.